# ExceptionInInitializerError while reading .xlsm with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I wrapped apache-poi in an OSGI bundle with these depencies:

- poi 3.13
- poi-ooxml 3.13
- poi-ooxml-schemas 3.13
- xmlbeans 2.3.0

And I try to read a .xlsm file like that:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
```

But I get this exception:

```
$ Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:162)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:142)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:273)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
```

I don't know if I miss a dependency or if my code is bad. Tried a lot of things.

Comment: What's the full stacktrace, including the caused-by?

Comment: Also, [as per the Apache POI docs, don't use an InputStream if you have a File!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Answer (score 1):

`ExceptionInInitializerError` usually indicate that some static-code-block in one of the classes that were loaded threw a RuntimeException which was not caught anywhere and thus caused Java to stop execution of that Thread.

In your case at `OPCPackage.java:162` the class `ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller` is likely used the first time and thus loaded, this one loads `PackagePropertiesMarshaller` which has a static-code-block which handles initialization of XML-Parser related functionality.

This would indicate that the version/style of JVM that you are using has crippled XML-Parsing support or is configured incorrectly.

Please try with a recent Oracle Java VM to see if this causes the problem to go away.

Another possible cause is if you include some other third-party libraries which drag in some other XML Parser which does not adhere to the Java-XML-interfaces fully and thus causes a problem here. Try with a reduced test-application to see if this is the case.